# Multiple facebook and twitter icons on custom share filter chooser intent in android

Tags: android, facebook, twitter

I'm using below code to share image on facebook, twitter, google+ and other social apps. Image is uploaded from device's external storage. But when I show chooser there're multipe facebook and twitter icons. How can I restrict to show only one icon? Below is the code.

```
public void customShare() {
    if (file.exists()) {
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/jpeg");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfo) {
            String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            Intent targetedShareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            targetedShareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
            targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            targetedShareIntent.setPackage(packageName);
            if (packageName.equals("com.facebook.katana")  || packageName.equals("ru.ok.android") ||
                   packageName.equals("com.vkontakte.android") || packageName.equals("com.twitter.android")||
                    packageName.equals("com.whatsapp") || packageName.equals("org.telegram.messenger") ||
                    packageName.equals("com.google.android.apps.plus")) {

                targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShareIntent);
            }
        }
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(
                targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "");

        chooserIntent.putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
        startActivity(chooserIntent);
    }
}
```

This what is shown on chooser.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/jpeg");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
```

above code retune all the activity that has action type `Intent.ACTION_SEND` Facebook have multiple activities with this type simpled so resInfo 
 have multiple entries with same packagename value com.facebook.katana.check the activity with all entry using `resolveInfo.activityInfo.targetActivity`

```
 for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfo) {
            String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;


            Intent targetedShareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            targetedShareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
            targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            targetedShareIntent.setPackage(packageName);
            if (packageName.equals("com.facebook.katana") || packageName.equals("ru.ok.android") ||
                    packageName.equals("com.vkontakte.android") || packageName.equals("com.twitter.android") ||
                    packageName.equals("com.whatsapp") || packageName.equals("org.telegram.messenger") ||
                    packageName.equals("com.google.android.apps.plus")) {

                Log.d("PackageAdded", packageName+"  = ====== "+ resolveInfo.activityInfo.targetActivity);
                targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShareIntent);
            }
        }
```

for the solution, you can just remove existing package that is already added to targetedShareIntents.